# Is there a way to reassign a variable to a different trait implemetation?

Tags: rust, traits

Can I have a variable that I can assign to 2 structs that implement the same trait?

Simple example

```
trait Node {
    fn some_function(&self);
}
struct Edge {
    begin: bool,
}
struct Repeat {
    bar: usize,
}

impl Node for Edge {
    fn some_function(&self) { /*...*/ }
}

impl Node for Repeat {
    fn some_function(&self) { /*...*/ }
}

impl Edge {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Edge { begin: true }
    }
}

impl Repeat {
    fn new(ch: u8) -> Repeat
    {
       Repeat { bar: 100 }
    }
}

fn process_seq<'a>(bytes: &'a [u8]) -> Option<impl Node> {
    let mut node = None;
    // These both implement the same trait
    node = Some(as_node(Edge::new()));
    node = Some(as_node(Repeat::new()));
    //
    node
}
```

This is what I've tried so far

// A function to cast back to node

```
fn as_node<T: Node>(t: T) -> impl Node {
    t
}

error[E0308]: mismatched types
note: expected type `regexgen::Edge`
      found type `regexgen::Repeat`
```

// Change new() constructors to return impl Node

```
impl Edge {
    fn new() -> impl Node {
        Edge { begin: true }
    }
}

impl Repeat {
    fn new(ch: u8) -> impl Node
    {
       Repeat { bar: 100 }
    }
}
```

but that gives 2 similar but opaque types which might look the same but I know Rust treats those differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a variable whose value can be an option of an implementation of a trait.

You can define your variable as having type `Option<Box<dyn Node>>`.

The boxing is needed because the size isn't known at this point.

And you can create a value like this:

```
let mut node: Option<Box<dyn Node>> = Some(Box::new(Edge::new()));
```

**Note:**

As the `dyn` keyword makes it clear, the functions to call are dynamically found which impacts performances. And the heap allocated box content can also be a (small) burden to your performances. Of course the impact is usually negligible.